# Read a file and split with delimiter

Tags: php, delimiter

I have this text file

```
acmst501:57:Runningacmst506:201:Runningacmst506:203:Runningacmst506:209:Runningacmst506:213:Failed
```

which I want to split with delimiters. I have this code working.

```
    <?php
function parseFile($filename, $delimiter) {
    global $splitcontents;
    //$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
    //$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));
    //fclose ($fd);
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);
    return $splitcontents;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Read file and split with delimiter</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    parseFile("c:\emap\asrvr505-cslot_state.txt",":");
    foreach ( $splitcontents as $value ) {
        echo "<b>$value<br>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output I get is this:

```
acmst501
57
Running acmst506
201
Running acmst506
203
Running acmst506
209
Running acmst506
213
Failed
```

However, I would like it to be something like :

```
acmst501
57
Running
acmst506
201
Running
...
```

So basically, i want to separate the Running/Failed part from the acmst field.

How do I separate these? Also, is my function correct so I can use it with different files in the same PHP file? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));
fclose ($fd);
```

puts the entire buffer at once in `$contents` - if that's your goal, you might as well use `file_get_contents()`

In your input you have: `Runningacmst506`. There is no delimiter there. I assume you are splitting on the `:`, but there is no colon near Running.

Do you have a typo in your example input?

If you clarify your input I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Hi Ariel. Thanks! Yes there is no delimiter between `Runningacmst506` but i need to separate them. The good thing is the acmst part is constant, only the number is changed. Also, the running part might be changed to failed, etc.

Comment: @JudeJitsu Then use `explode()` with 'acmst' as the delimiter. You will end up with Just the number, without the word acmst, but you can then put it back. You can also get fancy with regex's, but I think for you it's better to just write a loop. Although if you want to be semi-fancy use `array_map()` with an anonymous function.

Comment: I have applied the `file_get_contents` as per your advice. Do you mean that I should explode `$splitcontents`, because I keep getting errors if i do it. About the `array_map()`, how can I do that?

Comment: @JudeJitsu You have to explode each array element of `$splitcontents` you called it `$value` in your code, not the entire `$splitcontents` at once. Or use `array_map()` which can work on the entire array in one shot. See: http://www.php.net/array_map please try it first, and if you can't get it to work post a new question.